# Do we need to check in *.xcuserstate?

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control

I am wondering do we need to checkin *.xcuserstate file? I think it is not part of source code? But maybe it is important to maintain it in the source control?

Comment: related: [Git ignore file for Xcode projects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49478/457406)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you should ignore that file from source control. It's a user-specific file used by Xcode to set up your workspace for you, so you're right that it's not part of the source code.

Comment: A `.gitignore` for reference: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore