# Xcode tree conflicts on merge

Tags: xcode, git, merge, git-flow, tree-conflict

I'm working in team with git and every time we try to merge code we have a tree conflict.
We're currently working with git flow and we usually start features from develop, when the task is finished one of us merges one feature into the other and then merge it into develop.
The problem is than every time we try to merge one feature into another we have a tree conflict in xcode and we don't know how to fix it.

The error message is: "The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts."

Comment: Usually I experience these, if I was tracking generated files. Files which are generated by Xcode. Are you finding tree conflicts with these generated files?

Comment: Hi, do you find how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please add .gitignore file if you have not added.

Refer link given below.

[How to add .gitignore file into Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517440/how-to-add-gitignore-file-into-xcode-project)

If it doesn't solve your problem, you can try to merge using terminal using given below command.

```
git mergetool
```

And then if there are any conflict then you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by merging differently:
First I merged feature1 into develop, then I merged develop into feature2 and final feature2 in develop.
In this way there aren't tree conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. The problem was that the `master` branch had uncommited changes (unrelated to the changes in the other one). Switching to `master` and committing the changes allowed me to merge the feature branch back into `master`.

Try committing all the changes on all the branches and try the merge again after that.