# How to display all files in Project Navigator in Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

Some files on my Swift project, like `circle.yml` and `.gitignore`, aren't shown in the Xcode 9 Navigator. How do I get them so show up?

Comment: As much as I'd like it to be different, I'll accept it. I don't understand the downvote though. I haven't used Xcode in years and if that's a stupid question for the seasoned MacOS devs, it isn't for the beginners. Anyways, if you submit an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It might be useful: [How to add .gitignore file into Xcode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517440/how-to-add-gitignore-file-into-xcode-project)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Xcode project navigator is not a file browser. Just because something is in your project folder, doesn't mean the project is aware of it. The project isn't magically watching the project folder to see what's put in there. It knows about the stuff that *it* put in there, of course.
But you want something to be seen by the project, and you *yourself* put it into the project folder without telling the project that you did so, then just drag it into the project navigator to bring it to Xcode's attention. Note that you should decline Xcode's offer to make this part of the *target*. You don't want a *.gitignore* file to be built into your app; you just want the convenience of accessing it thru Xcode and the project window.