# Why doesn't my project .gitignore work? The global .gitignore does

Tags: git, gitignore, ubuntu-18.04

I can't get git to ignore any files or folders listed in .gitignore.

1. Create empty .gitignore file in same folder as .git. To be clear, it's not inside of the .git folder, it's in the project root folder.
2. Add one line "stupidfilename" to .gitignore.
3. Create "stupidfilename", which has never existed in the repo.
4. Run "git add ."
5. Gasp as "stupidfilename" is staged.

Files listed in my global .gitignore file are successfully ignored. But I'd like to have project-level ignores.

Setup

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Oh-my-zsh
- WSL2, and also GCP
- Cmder

Any idea what's going on here? I can't find any explanation on the internet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git check-ignore -vn --no-index stupidfilename`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the .gitignore file belong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698148/where-does-the-gitignore-file-belong)

Comment: Thanks @bk2204, didn't know about that command!

Answer (score 2):

`.gitignore` does not work if you put it in the `.git` directory. 
It should be in your source or working directory

Possibly a repeat of this question
[Where does the .gitignore file belong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698148/where-does-the-gitignore-file-belong)